# Share module between multiple projects in a monorepo

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a small monorepo with a few projects (they share the same data stores, so it's easier to have them together in a monorepo for development and testing). Each project is in its own folder, with its own package.json. Each project is meant to be deployed on its own (independent of the other projects).

I would like to share some code between the projects. I want to maintain their relative independence, so I'd rather not have to create a "build" step in the root repo folder, as well as having each project's own build step. Ideally deployment of each project would continue to be done in the project's folder, without it needing to know about other projects.

I know I could create an npm module in the repo and `npm link` to it from each project. This is the solution I'm leaning toward. But I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea.

Here's an example of what the directory structure kinda looks like:

```
/package.json
/docker-compose.yml
/project-1/package.json
/project-2/package.json
```

If I went with the `npm link` solution, I would add something like a `project-shared` folder and link to it from `project-1` and `project-2`.

Answer (score 8):

This is the npm link solution I'm using at the moment. It seems like an OK solution, so I thought I'd post it as an answer. I haven't yet implemented the deployment stuff for this project, so I don't know how well deployment will work with this. I'm hoping it will deploy the linked module along with everything else.

The project directory structure looks like:

```
/package.json
/docker-compose.yml
/project-1/package.json
/project-2/package.json
/project-shared/package.json
```

In each project's package.json (`project-1` and `project-2`), I added this postinstall script:

```js
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm link ../project-shared"
},
```

So the link will be created during the normal setup of the project.

NOTE: For some reason this doesn't work using a `preinstall` script (the link won't be created, though it looks like it's run). `postinstall` works just fine.

I'm not quite sure how dependency installation works for the shared module (e.g. if the shared module's dependencies will be installed when the projects link to it, or if I'll have to install them independently).

One problem I encountered is that Docker Compose doesn't play well with linked packages (the symlinked folder won't point to the correct location inside the container). I fixed this by mounting the shared folder over the symlink in the node_modules folder. For example, for `project-1`:

```yaml
volumes:
  - "./project-1/:/home/node/app:ro"
  - "./project-shared/:/home/node/app/node_modules/project-shared:ro"
```

**EDIT: Sept 4, 2020**

Wanted to drop a note that I've been using this in production for a while and it works great. One issue I've noticed in dev, with the shared library mounted in the Docker container, is when you `npm install` from your host computer it will run `postinstall` and symlink your shared library folder. This is expected, except in Docker it messes up your mount. The solution I've found is to stop Docker, remove the link, re-create the folder, and start up Docker again. A better solution might be replacing your `postinstall` script with something like this:

```
"postinstall": "test -d node_modules/project-shared || npm link ../project-shared"
```

This will only link the folder if it doesn't already exist. I've only tested this a little bit, so I'm not sure if I'm missing any weird edge cases.

**EDIT: Feb 22, 2023**

These days, this is not a good option. All package managers now support monorepos and you can easily include dependencies from other packages in the repo.

Comment: Don't you first need to run `npm link` in `project-shared` to make it available for linking? This may not be an issue for you locally, because it only has to done once, but I'm wondering how to best solve it for other developers who create a fresh clone of the repo. Too bad the linking status cannot be persisted more explicitly.

Comment: @bluenote10 No, I think that's only if you want it as a sort of "global" package so that you can treat it like a normal npm package and not provide a path. If you just provide a path to `npm link` it will link whatever's there.

Comment: @bluenote10 it is not needed to run `npm link` in the shared project because running `npm link ../project-shared` makes under the hood `(cd ../project-shared; npm link)`. The shared project will be always linked to the `/node_modules/<package>` global node folder